# How do I create an online community within my organization?

Tags: community

I need to create an online community for the members of a particular committee.

Comment: I would welcome guidance on setting up an online community for a particular committee in my organization.

Comment: Assign specific Role for all the member of the group in CMS and provide user login for them - That should work

Comment: Thank you. What is CMS?

Comment: do you have a website ? if you have a website build in Wordpress or Drupal then front facing of the website is CMS (content management system) CiviCRM will be in the backend (CRM)

Comment: you need to spell out what functionality you need your online community to have - one option would be Drupal Groups - but hard to guess what you actually want

Comment: Sorry, it is Drupal, and I have been directed to this webpage https://new.uschess.org/documentation/governance-creating-new-committee

Comment: Ah, that looks like you want to create a community within the uschess.org site?  'Community' is not a standard CiviCRM feature so you'll need to talk with the admins for that site.